# event.target is undefined in events

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

How can one use `each` input values in `events`? Hope my below code will explain you well.

HTML:

```
<template name="UpdateAge">
    {{#each Name}}
    <div data-action="showPrompt">
       <div>
          Some content
       </div>

       <div>
         <div>
            Some content
         </div>
       </div>
       <div>
           Name : {{name}}
           Age : <input type="text" name="age" value="{{age}}"/> //I need to access age values in event
       </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
<template>
```

JS:

```
Template.UpdateAge.events({
  'click [data-action="showPrompt"]': function (event, template) {
        console.log(event.target.age.value); // TypeError: event.target.age.value is undefined
  }
});
```

I dont know whether my approach is good for passing parameter values to `events` so suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Well, your error message doesn't say that `event.target` was undefined, does it? However, hardly any target does have an `.age` property, so accessing `.value` there would throw.

Comment: Yeah, still the `<div>` does not magically gain a `.age` property by that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the notation you are using is valid only for form elements and when event.target IS a form element.

```
event.target.age.value
```

[event.target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp) is the element where the event occurred, [event.currentTarget](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp) is the element which has attached the event handler

if you replace `div` with `form` and replace `target` with `currentTarget` then it will work

```
event.currentTarget.age.value
```

[here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/597fym2d/) using your code

Comment: I changed `div` to `form` but same error occurs. I think am not submitting the form. In my case I don't have submit button.

Comment: event.target is the element on which you clicked. so if you click on the input box event.target is the the input box, not the form. the form element will be `currentTarget`

Comment: Thanks, best way for me, works perfectly. This saved my life :)

Answer (score 1):

If the event is bound on the container div then the input should be searched from target, because `event.target` would give you the element whom the event was attached to.

To access any value within the `div` you must first get access to that element and then use the properties of that element to access whatever needed - `.value` in this case.